# MySQL Client in a Cocoa App

Tags: mysql, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL database from a macOS app (written in Swift).

I've embedded the MySQL C library (libmysqlclient.18.dylib) into the app, and imported the headers using a module map. Everything seems to compile and link correctly.

For some reason, I can't get the client to actually connect to a database. `mysql_real_connect()` produces `Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on [host]`. The credentials are correct, but it won't connect to any database (remote or localhost).

As a test, I created a nearly identical application using Swift Package Manager (command line app), rather than a Cocoa app. The MySQL C library is embedded using the exact same process, and it connects to databases exactly as you'd expect.

So the problem somehow stems from the Cocoa application. Is there any difference between a command line app and a Cocoa app that would prevent me from connecting to a database? Maybe something preventing the outbound requests?

PS - I also set App Transport Security to `Allow Arbitrary Loads`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Is the Cocoa application sandboxed?

Comment: @l'L'l that was it! I mostly deal with iOS so I'm not very familiar with Cocoa apps. Can you explain why sandboxing would have prevented the connection?

Comment: Sandboxed apps need to use entitlements in order to access much of anything outside of it's container. There's a grip of information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW4), and [this might give you a better idea](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW6) to determine if your app should be sanboxed or not.

Comment: Thanks for the info - that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I guess it's a sandbox restriction, so you just need to un-sandbox the application.

Simply edit `AppName.entitlements` and set `App Sandbox` to `No`.